# Modify a cell in Google Sheet using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am a beginner in google app script. I am creating a resident payment system where the user can change their password upon logging in. So now, I have done the html part for changing the password but I dont know how to do the coding in order to change the password. I have attached some pictures and my code to explain myself better. Thank you so much guys.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1775459006  - Link to google sheet

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw_A-XRlXtR9qGNvMKVrorMIg71hwHt0DrHRiNGVYZdURbadYgUtOIkJPsvuYsBK7Fe/exec - Link to Web App

https://script.google.com/d/1DdRKqUX__-ZITUgTZanQ_A7hUL1kcc0TZOeFmn58wYsX_o_7cqNExnYo/edit?usp=sharing - Link to app script

[image][image]

**Code for Code.gs**

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1775459006";
var streetSheetName = "JALAN SANGGUL 4";

function doGet(e) {
  var streetSheetName = "JALAN SANGGUL 4"; // Added
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("streetSheetName", streetSheetName); // Added
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppLogin');
}

function checkLogin(username, password) {
  var found_record = '';
  var name = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++) {
   if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase() && webAppSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue() == password) {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
     name = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue().toUpperCase() + " " + webAppSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toUpperCase();
     streetSheetName = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue().toUpperCase();
   } else if (username.toUpperCase() == 'ADMIN' && password == 'ADMINPASSWORD') {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
     name = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue().toUpperCase() + " " + webAppSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toUpperCase();
     streetSheetName = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue().toUpperCase();
   }    
  }

PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("streetSheetName", streetSheetName); // Added
if(found_record == '') {
  found_record = 'FALSE'; 
}

  return [found_record, username,name];
}

function GetRecords(username,filter) {
  var filteredDataRangeValues = GetUsernameAssociatedProperties(username);
  var resultArray = GetPaymentRecords(filteredDataRangeValues,filter);
  return resultArray;
}

function GetUsernameAssociatedProperties(username) {
  var filteredDataRangeValues = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var dataRangeValues = displaySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (username.toUpperCase() == 'ADMIN') {
    dataRangeValues.shift();
    filteredDataRangeValues = dataRangeValues;
  } else {
    filteredDataRangeValues = dataRangeValues.filter(row => row[0].toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase());
  }
  return filteredDataRangeValues;  
}

function GetPaymentRecords(userProperties,filter) {
  var streetSheetName = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("streetSheetName"); // Added
  var transpose = m => m[0].map((_, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
  var resultArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName(streetSheetName);
  var addressValues = displaySheet.getRange("B:C").getValues();
  var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange(1, 7, displaySheet.getLastRow(), displaySheet.getLastColumn() - 6).getValues();
  //Logger.log(addressValues);
  //Logger.log(transpose(paidMonthValues));
  userProperties.forEach((v, i) => {
    var userHouseNumber = v[1];
    var userStreet = v[2];
    var column = addressValues.reduce(function callbackFn(accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
      if (currentValue[0] == userHouseNumber && currentValue[1] == userStreet) {
        return index
      } else {
        return accumulator
      }
    }, '');
    //Logger.log(column);
    Logger.log(filter)
    Logger.log(paidMonthValues);
    
    if(filter=="None"){
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }else{
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        if(element[0].includes(filter))return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }
    
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
    //Logger.log(resultArray);  
  })

  //Remove null elements
  resultArray = resultArray.filter(element=>{
    Logger.log(element!=null)
    return element != null;
  });
  return resultArray;
}
```

**Code for WebAppLogin.html**

```
    function changePassword(){
      var result = confirm("Want to Change Password?");
      if (result) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          .getEmail()
        alert('Password changed');
      }
```

Comment: I didn't go through all your code since it's so long, but I guess you want to handle this through the client-side function `changePassword`. If that's the case, in `changePassword` you should call a server-side function that would change the password value in the sheet. In your code, you're calling the function `getEmail` which doesn't exist anywhere in your code, and as the success handler you are calling `updateButton`, which I don't see anywhere either. Can you clarify this? Also, I'd suggest you to provide a minimal reproduce example in order to focus on your actual issue.

Comment: @Iamblichus  Bro thank you so much for replying. I really need your help bro. I have updated some things in my post bro. Hope it will make you understand better. I want to enable the user to change the password after they have logged in bro. But I am not very sure on how to do the coding. Hope you can help me with it. **Username : JJACKSON Password : PASSWORD1** you can use this credentials to log in to the web app bro.

Comment: When I saw your shared sample Spreadsheet, it seems that your sample Spreadsheet is different from the sample Spreadsheet of your image. For example, the column "A" of the sheet "USERNAMES" is different. In your shared Spreadsheet, the column "A" is `4`. How about this? And also, what is the function `updateButton` of `.withSuccessHandler(updateButton)` in Javascript side?

Comment: @Tanaike Bro it just the same you can notice it now yesterday I mistaken changed it in to 4 sorry about that.

Comment: @Tanaike and about the ``.withSuccessHandler(updateButton)`` . Bro I seriously dont know what I am doing there for change password function I think its wrong. Could you help me with it I got that function form one of website but I dont know how to do the coding properly

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, 1. The column "A" of the sheet "USERNAMES" is "USERNAME". Is my understanding correct? 2. I cannot still understand about `.withSuccessHandler(updateButton)`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal of `.withSuccessHandler(updateButton)`? For example, `alert('Password changed')` is shown in the function `updateButton`?

Comment: @Tanaike 1st one is you are correct bro. 2nd one bro the ignore the coding bro because it is wrong I just copied from a website I dont have an idea on how to do it. Basically, bro what I am trying to do is bro if you go to web app and login with **Username : JJACKSON Password : PASSWORD1**  there will an option for the user to change the password bro

Comment: Now I saw your new sample Spreadsheet. At the column "A" of "USERNAMES", only the header title is changed. And, the data rows are not changed. In your actual situation, is this correct?

Comment: @Tanaike And the user's password is in USERNAMES worksheet in google sheet

Comment: @Tanaike You are correct bro

Comment: Thank you for replying. For my question of `Now I saw your new sample Spreadsheet. At the column "A" of "USERNAMES", only the header title is changed. And, the data rows are not changed. In your actual situation, is this correct?`, you said `@Tanaike You are correct bro`. I think that in this case, `Username : JJACKSON Password : PASSWORD1` cannot be used. How about this? You want to change the user names? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I am sorry for not explaining myself better. Now if you log in https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzZYOB69Pv2RZV3qD2ugcoM4MZIHgwNuac94RkNxXBKk37xhKXT6Fb0XTQAnSHTcB0/exec in this website using the credentials bro they just can just change the password bro. For example bro, now logging in with **Username : JJACKSON Password : PASSWORD1** after logging in the JJACKSON should able to change his password so if he change it the data in cell F2

Comment: @Tanaike Bro bro I guess I found out why you didnt understand just now

Comment: @Tanaike I have changed the usernames bro and I forget about it edy. So so sorry about it

Comment: @Tanaike Can you have a look on it again. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: @Tanaike Really sorry for messing things up bro. Now things will be fine bro

Comment: From your replying and your updated sample Spreadsheet, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your this question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the button of "Change Password" is clicked and input the value and click "Save changes", you want to change the password in the Spreadsheet.

### Modification points:

- In your script, when "Save changes" button is clicked, it seems that `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).getEmail()` is run. But, unfortunately, in your script, there are no functions of `updateButton` and `getEmail`. By this, an error occurs.
- When I saw your shared sample Spreadsheet, it seems that your sample Spreadsheet is different from the sample Spreadsheet of your image. For example, the column "A" of the sheet "USERNAMES" is different. In your shared Spreadsheet, the column "A" is `4`.

  - From this situation, from your replying of `it just the same you can notice it now yesterday I mistaken changed it in to 4 sorry about that.`, I understood that the column "A" of the sheet "USERNAMES" is "USERNAME".
- About `updateButton`, in this answer, `alert('Password changed')` is run as the sample.
- In order to update the password of Spreadsheet, it is required to use the username and the inputted password. And, it is also required to prepare the function at Google Apps Script side.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Javascript side:

#### From:

```
function GetRecords() {
  var spin = "<span class=\"spinner-border spinner-border-sm\" role=\"status\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>";
  spin += " Loading...";
  document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = spin;

  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

#### To:

```
var username = ""; // Added
function GetRecords() {
  var spin = "<span class=\"spinner-border spinner-border-sm\" role=\"status\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>";
  spin += " Loading...";
  document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = spin;

  username = document.getElementById("username").value; // Modified
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

And, please modify `changePassword()` as follows.

```
function changePassword(){
  var result = confirm("Want to Change Password?");
  if (result) {
    var newPassword = document.getElementById("newPassword").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => alert('Password changed')).changePassword(username, newPassword);
  }
}
```

### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following function to Google Apps Script side.

```
function changePassword(username, newPassword) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(username).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (range) {
    range.offset(0, 6).setValue(newPassword);
  }
}
```

### Note:

- In this case, when the password is changed, the alert of "Password changed" can be seen. And, the column "G" of Sheet "USERNAMES" is changed.

Comment: Thank you so so much for being with me bro. I dont know how to thank you actually thanks alot bro. I really appreciate your help for me bro. After I have completed everything I will definitely inform you about the final output bro. Finally bro I swear I wont annoy you again, I promise. I have a question on how to add a row in google sheet I really hope that you would me a hand for it. Thank you so much for being with me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640822/adding-a-row-based-on-condition-using-google-app-sheet - Sorry bro. Can you have a look on the post  and help me bro. I really appreciate your help bro. Thank you bro